# How to use login/ register page with php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a bootstrap and I want to use the login/ register page with php. I changed index.html to index.php same with `register.php` and `login.php`

So this is the section from my `login.php` file that used to be `login.html`.

I have a `base.php` file that has the information for my database. I can use the database just fine, I have done it with simpler code.

My question is : **Do I add the php code in this page, and how do I do it?**

```html
<div class="sign-in-form-top">
 <h1>Inicio de Sesión</h1>
</div>
<div class="signin">
 <div class="signin-rit">
  <span class="checkbox1">
   <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</label>
  </span>
  <p><a href="#">Haz clic aquí</a> </p>
  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
 </div>
 <form>
  <div class="log-input">
   <div class="log-input-left">
    <input type="text" class="user" value="Tu Correo Electrónico" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Tu Correo Electrónico';}"/>
   </div>
   <span class="checkbox2">
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked=""><i> </i></label>
   </span>
   <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="log-input">
   <div class="log-input-left">
    <input type="password" class="lock" value="password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email address:';}"/>
   </div>
   <span class="checkbox2">
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked=""><i> </i></label>
   </span>
   <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Inicia Sesión">
 </form>  
</div>
<div class="new_people">
 <h2>¿Todavía no sos miembro?</h2>
 <p>Crea tu cuenta, es fácil y rápido.</p>
 <a href="register.php">¡Registrate Ahora!</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **you should search on the internet** there are a number of tutorials are available for login and register demo.

Quick solution.

```
<?php
include('base.php');
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }
    else
    {
        // Define $username and $password
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
        // Selecting Database
        $db = mysql_select_db("company", $connection); //$connection -> Connection of the database from base.php

        // Assuming you have table LOGIN or Change the table name with your along with the database columns
        // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
        $query = mysql_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($rows == 1) {
            // Session to check whether the user is logged in or not in another pages
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username; // Initializing Session
            header("location: PageYouWantAfterLogin.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
        } else {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
        }
        mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
    }
}
?>
```

Please change the code for textbox and submit button

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="user" value="Tu Correo Electrónico" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Tu Correo Electrónico';}"/>

<input type="password" name="password" class="lock" value="password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email address:';}"/>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
```

Also, change the `<form>` tag to below code. Read more about form [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just send the form to login.php itself by using PHP self-method. Make sure your form have action and method.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login-form'])) {

      // Your Code Here

    }
?>

<html>
<body>

<form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
     E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
     <button type="submit" name="login-form"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Or you can send the form to another PHP file.